# Returning a range table. How?

Tags: range, abap

I would like to write a function module that returns a range table.  Is that possible and if so, how?

Comment: What version of SAP are you using?  6.0 should have plenty of range tables predefined that you can specify in the FM signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structure of a typed range is like this :

```
**Name**  **Type**
SIGNT      VARV_SIGN
OPTION     TVARV_OPTI
LOW        your-type
HIGH       your-type
```

You can create this structure in the dictionary, as well as a table of those, and then use it in the FM signature.

Also, a generic structure already exists : `RSDSSELOPT` (along with a table type `RSELOPTION`).