# How to make a search in SAP with multiple values

Tags: abap, opensql

My question is how can I make a search in SAP like the search in MySQL.

For example:

```
select * from [table] where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

there are several possibilities.

- you can use the addtion to select statement 'for all entries in t' where t is an internal table. you can then use the internal table in the WHERE statement

> ```
> SELECT carrid connid fldate     
>   FROM sflight     
>   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE result_tab   
>    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN entry_tab   
>  WHERE carrid = entry_tab-carrid   
>    AND connid = entry_tab-connid.
> ```

- you can also use a range table (as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702429/returning-a-range-table-in-abap/3707955#3707955) answer) and use it in your WHERE condition :

> ```
> ... WHERE field in range_table...
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other suggestions (for all entries, range table)  you should be able to use the format specified in your question.

For example, the below works in  my system.

```
data: t_t001w type STANDARD TABLE OF t001w.

select * 
  from t001w 
  into table t_t001w
 where werks in (1001, 1002).
```